# Is Homebrew safe for Mac?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I wonder if Homebrew is safe for Mac users...

Do you have any bad experience with this software (like malware for example)?

Comment: Some interesting info here... https://applehelpwriter.com/2018/03/21/how-homebrew-invites-users-to-get-pwned/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Homebrew on its own acts like a command-line App Store.

- It's safe, if you know what you're downloading.
- It [uses SHA256 to fingerprint](https://docs.brew.sh/Checksum_Deprecation) the downloaded instructions as a validity / tamper detection verification check.
- It’s open, so you could validate what it’s downloading and how it
  works.
- It [refuses to use `sudo`](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad) to intentionally be safer.

If you are concerned about downloading hijacked binaries, verify the SHA/SHA1 sum of the binary you've downloaded against the SHA/SHA1 sum published by the developer, usually on their webpage.

Despite a long track record of people not pushing malware or bad code to the system, it would be good hygiene to start validating downloads.

Comment: I think one thing that people might dislike (security-wise) with homebrew is that it alters permissions for `usr/local`, `/usr/local/bin` for example.

Comment: See this article for security concerns: https://applehelpwriter.com/2018/03/21/how-homebrew-invites-users-to-get-pwned/

Comment: @JimAho That article at applehelpwriter is outdated and incorrect. Brew no longer leaves /usr/local/ owned by the user.

Comment: @TJLuoma When i yesterday was going to install brew, it explicitly said that it would alter permission for those directories, make me (the current user) admin of those directories. Are you sure it's outdated? A reference to some docs about this would be good.

Comment: I have 4 installations of `brew` and `/usr/local/` is owned by root in each case. However, `/usr/local/bin` is owned by my user. Whether that's a realistic security issue is up to each user to consider. If you're the only user of your Mac, I don't see any realistic security implications that I would worry about. YMMV.

Comment: PLEASE verify the SHA/SHA1 as outlined. In this day we're getting increasing issues with security and everyone should be doing their part. If the SHA does not match notify the developer immediately. Welcome to the new "safe".

Comment: As of Nov 2016, Homebrew is using SHA256. SHA1 was deprecated. https://docs.brew.sh/Checksum_Deprecation

Comment: Brew issued in 2018 [security incident disclosure](https://brew.sh/2018/08/05/security-incident-disclosure/) after [this article](https://medium.com/@vesirin/how-i-gained-commit-access-to-homebrew-in-30-minutes-2ae314df03ab) by Eric Holmes